# What ever happened to on disk bitmap indexes?

Tags: postgresql

Now PostgreSQL does not support bitmap index. I found that someone tried to implement it before.

- wiki:https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bitmap_Indexes
- code: https://github.com/jiayuasu/bitmap-postgresql
- email thread: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/46602F78.9050502%40dunslane.net

Anyone knows what ever happened that it didn't get merged?

Comment: "PostgreSQL does not support bitmap index" - why do you think that?

Comment: @ Richard Huxton PostgreSQL support bitmap index scan, does not support on-disk bitmap index like Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap indexes are mostly useless: they make DML very hard.

PostgreSQL doesn't need them, because it has something much better: bitmap index scans. They can operate on regular B-tree indexes and have practically all advantages of bitmap indexes.

What happened to the patch: according to my reading of the thread, it just never got in commitable shape, and the discussion on its merits didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Only specific scenarios are suitable for using bitmap index, such as distinct values are few and rarely modified, like gender. Yes, DML is really not easy to deal with.

Comment: You could experiment with GIN indexes. They are good for repeating values. New features in v12 and particularly in v13 make B-tree indexes for columns with few distinct values much better.